# UICollectionViewCell with UIScrollView cancels didSelectItemAtIndexPath

Tags: uiscrollview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a `UICollectionView` that horizontally scrolls to show one `UICollectionViewCell` at a time. Each `UICollectionViewCell` the has a vertically scrolling `UIScrollView` as subview for scrolling the contents of the cell. It is only 90 % or so of the inner part of the `UICollectionViewCell` that is covered by the `UIScrollView` - i.e. the outer frame of the cell is not covered by this.

It turns out that the part of the `UICollectionViewCell` that is covered by the `UIScrollView`cancels the `UICollectionView` delegate `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`. Thus when a simple tap happens within the `UIScrollView` this method is *not* invoked, whereas if the tap happens on the outer part of the cell, i.e. outside the `UIScrollView`, this method *is* invoked.

Any suggestions as to how to achieve a setup where it is possible to invoke the `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` method even when the tap happens within the `UIScrollView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tap on the `UIScrollView` is used to see whether scrolling should be done.

You should [catch the single tap on the UIScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5660678/single-double-tap-recognition-on-uiscrollview) itself and pass it on to the surrounding `UICollectionViewCell`.

Comment: Thanks! I found this answer a tiny bit better: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5216518/746968

Comment: @Zappel How then would you forward the tap to the UICollectionView to emulate an interactive selection tap that also fires the UICollectionView's selection delegate methods?

Comment: -1 You should definetly explain how you would "pass it on to the surrounding UICollectionViewCell"

Answer (score 37):

I found that the most effective approach is to steal the `panGestureRecognizer`, exposed by `UIScrollView` and disable `userInteraction` on the `scrollView`. That way, you get the behavior of the scrollview but maintain the interaction on the collection view. On your `UICollectionViewCell` subclass:

```
self.scrollView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
[self.contentView addGestureRecognizer:self.scrollView.panGestureRecognizer];
```

This is a method Apple recommends and demonstrates in WWDC 2014 session 235 (Advanced Scrollviews and Touch Handling Techniques)

Comment: This solution seems to be by far the cleanest way to solve this problem. Thanks!

Comment: This is an awesome solution, but it doesn't work if your scrollView contains buttons :(

Comment: Yes this is the best solution, because it only requires 2 lines of code, and you can still use the `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` function. Good job!

Answer (score 6):

Here's a UIScrollView subclass approach that maintains cell selection functionality, and also allows for UIControl selection (buttons, etc) both in & outside of the scrollview.

**Swift 3**

```
class CellContentScrollView: UIScrollView {

  override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
    let hitTargetView = super.hitTest(point, with: event)
    return hitTargetView as? UIControl ?? (hitTargetView == self ? nil : superview)
  }

  override func didMoveToSuperview() {
    superview?.addGestureRecognizer(panGestureRecognizer)
  }

}
```

**Swift 2**

```
class CellContentScrollView: UIScrollView {

    // MARK: - UIView override

    override func hitTest(point: CGPoint, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
        let hitTargetView = super.hitTest(point, withEvent: event)
        return hitTargetView as? UIControl ?? (hitTargetView == self ? nil : superview)
    }

    override func didMoveToSuperview() {
        superview?.addGestureRecognizer(panGestureRecognizer)
    }
}
```

**Objective-C**

```
@implementation CellContentScrollView

    #pragma mark - UIView override

    - (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
        UIView *hitTargetView = [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];

        if ([hitTargetView isKindOfClass:UIControl.class]) {
            return hitTargetView;
        } else if (hitTargetView != self) {
            return self.superview;
        }

        return nil;
    }

    - (void)didMoveToSuperview {
        [self.superview addGestureRecognizer:self.panGestureRecognizer];
    }

@end
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks

Comment: You saved my day! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**Add tap gesture to your super view**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(didTapView(gesture:)))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    }

@objc func didTapView(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    view.endEditing(true)
    let touchLocation:CGPoint = gesture.location(ofTouch: 0, in: self.collectionView)
    let indexPath = self.collectionView.indexPathForItem(at: touchLocation)
    if indexPath != nil {
        let cell = self.collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath!)
        if (cell?.isSelected)! {
            //PREFORM DESELECT
        } else {
            //PREFORM SELECT HERE
        }
    }
}
```