# My cells in a UICollectionViewCell automatically de-select or unhighlight on finger up

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I've got a UICollectionView, and on finger up (or mouse up) the cells deselect/dehighlight. I can see that they get highlighted on finger down (actually long finger down as it's inside a uiscrollview), but as soon as you let go they get de-highlighted.

And (when i did have a delegate set), the didSelectItemAtIndexPath was not getting called.

Any suggestions?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14298650/uicollectionviewcell-with-uiscrollview-cancels-didselectitematindexpath

This seems to answer your question

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that there was a tap gesture recogniser on a superview that was greedily eating up all the tap gestures.