# selection not possible UICollectionView

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I create `ClothesCollectionView` that contains `ClothesCollectionViewCell` elements. One of the element is called `JeansCollectionViewCell` and is a `collectionView` on its own. This image probably makes it easier to understand

[image]

1 is `ClothesCollectionView`, 2 is `JeansCollectionViewCell` and 3 are cell on `JeansCollectionViewCell` called `JeanItemCell`.

When a `JeanItemCell` is selected, the delegate `didSelectItemAt` of `ClothesCollectionView` gets called but not the one of `JeansCollectionViewCell`, so I can not determine which `JeanItemCell` was selected.

**EDIT:**

I added this code found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14298650/uicollectionviewcell-with-uiscrollview-cancels-didselectitematindexpath) to JeansCollectionViewCell

```
override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
    let hitTargetView = super.hitTest(point, with: event)
    return hitTargetView as? UIControl ?? (hitTargetView == self ? nil : superview)
}

override func didMoveToSuperview() {
    superview?.addGestureRecognizer(collectionView.panGestureRecognizer)
}
```

Now, with this code, I am able to scroll horizontally on JeansCollectionViewCell which was not the case, but unfortunately also outside the cell. Everywhere from ClothesCollectionView I can scroll horizontally the Jeans items. I am still not able to detect taps on the items.

Comment: Did you _set_ a delegate for the JeansCollectionView?

Comment: Sure, datasource and delegate.

Comment: What if you set the outer collection view's delegate to return `false` from `collectionView(_:shouldSelectItemAt:)` for this cell? I'm thinking maybe the problem is that it is "swallowing" the selection and you might be able to prevent that, allowing the selection to pass on to the inner cell. Just a guess - I've never tried this.

Comment: I just tried it, unfortunately it didn't worked